# long running php script hangs

Tags: php, linux, bash

I have this set in my php script to make it supposedly run as long as it needs to to parse and do mysql queries and fetch images for over 100,000 rows.

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
#begin logging output
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

I run the command like this in shell:

```
nohup php myscript.php > output.txt
```

after running about 8 to 10 hours this script will still be running but execution just stops... no more output..  it's not a zombie process I checked top.  It hasn't met the memory limit either and if it did wouldn't it exit?

What is going on?  It's a real pain to babysit this script and write custom code to nudge it along.  What is going on?  I read up on unix maybe cleaning up zombies but it's not a zombie.  I know it's not php settings.. and it's not running through a webserver it's from command line only so what gives.

Comment: can't help you without knowing what it does, e.g. show some code.

Comment: How come you are running this over 8 hours? Why don't you split up the job into smaller more manageable chunks?

Comment: it loops through a csv file and the script is over 600 lines of code

Comment: @Layke because that takes a lot more work and time is pressing why not just run it all at once like it should?  then I don't have to manage it at all, I can just tell it to run and be done with it when I need to.

Comment: Anything in the error logs from when it runs? Sounds like it is most likely getting stuck in a loop somewhere.

Comment: @hukir none that I can find.  I have php putting all errors in a log file in /var/log and none of the errors are from myscript.php.  Also if I start the program from where it left off, it continues just fine and where it "ends" is on different lines, randomly, not the same ones.

Comment: @wolfe So have you found the exact solution ? How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long-running PHP scripts shouldn't die or hang without reason. I've had scripts that run continuously for 6 months +. There must be something else going on inside of your script body.

Comment: My program uses CURL to fetch external URLs if it needs to.  Maybe if the webserver 404 or 500's when it fetches the resource?  I don't know.  It's 836 lines of code that loop over a csv file.  It stops in random places from each start.  If it were consistent I could think you were on to something but I just don't know I was thinking maybe it's my unix environment somehow.

Comment: FYI, the 6-month + script was also using curl (curl_multi) to poll Twitter's API - hundreds of requests per second. If you handle the resources correctly and account for error conditions, you should be OK.

Comment: I'll try that and get back to you but.. it's hanging not on a fetch but just random parts of output I'm so confused

Comment: I added some retry methods we'll see if it was erroring out on that thank you

Comment: I have got it hanging up on the same part of the code each time now and have error handling for everything.. will let you know if this works.  The only part it hangs on didn't have a timeout just for that connection.  I set one so we'll see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you haven't detached your process correctly. Currently, if your process's parent die, your process will die too. If you place your process in background (create a real daemon), you'll not meet scuh trouble.

You can execute your PHP this way to really detach it :

```
php myscript.php > output.txt 2>&1 &
```

For your information :

```
> output.txt
```

will redirect standard output (ie. your echo, print etc) to output.txt file

```
2>&1
```

will redirect error output to standard output, writting it in the same output.txt file

```
&
```

is the most important thing in your case : it will detach your process to create a real daemon.

Edit : if you're having troubles while disconecting your shell, the most simple is to put your script on a bash script, for example `run.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
php myscript.php > output.txt 2>&1 &
```

And you'll run your script this way :

```
bash run.sh &
```

In such case, your shell will "think" your program has ended at the end of the shell script, not at the end of the php daemon.

Comment: I was doing this originally minus redirecting the error output as I did that initially.  The problem with using & is if your shell is disconnected from the server, or the tty is closed, that process ends.  Since my net goes out sometimes, that happened.  So I tried to use disown to fix this problem.  That worked but it still hang.  I am doing the nohup command because supposedly it is more robust than disown at preventing hangup/stopping execution and letting it run free.  So basically: nohup is everything & is but for different more robust reasons

Comment: okey I updated, the most simple is to use a shell script as intermediate... but you can also use an `exec()` call inside your php file with another argument. That's up to you.

Comment: This well-intentioned answer is misleading. Placing the process into the background (`&`) is not a sufficient solution. `nohup` (Most likely combined with `&`) is precisely what should be used in this scenario.